# Should I use boolean type for non yes/no answer variable?

Tags: c++

I was coding with a beginner C++ group and we were creating a 'Car' class. Someone suggested 'tyre type' as a possible variable/attribute to the class as a boolean type. Another person then asked whether booleans should be directly answerable with a yes/no.

I was just wondering the same. How do you best manage a variable this and how do you later specify two options, such as winter/summer, for this variable?

Comment: A boolean by definition has a value of True or False, which is the same as Yes or No, or On or Off. If you need to add Maybe or Could Be or something else, then it's no longer a boolean. So no - you should not use a boolean for tire type. What about tires that are neither winter or summer, such as off-road tires or racing tires or space-saving spares?

Comment: Depends on if there is one of two possibilities. If you are only going to work with two tire types then a boolean is perfectly fine to use.

Comment: I'd go for an `enum` of tyre types here for expandability and readability even if I only had two tyre types.

Comment: There's also the more philosophical stuff, the kinds of things that generally spark long debates in comments. For example: In real life there are more than two types of tires, it just so happens that your program only uses a small subset, which coincidentally happens to be the same size as the set of possible boolean values. So can we really say that a "tire type", conceptually, is a boolean value, even though the program happens to work with only two of them? Another example is, semantically, if it were a boolean, what would something like  `!someTireType` be trying to convey?

Comment: It depends on the kind of need..like use boolean for strict yes no but if ques. doesn't demands it , then there is no use of using it ! There are other ways of doing  it too !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, it depends.

Your goal is to write clear, readable, maintainable, and correct code. It's not so much that `bool` necessitates a yes vs. no answer as much as it is a question of whether or not using boolean (or any other type for that matter) helps you to meet these goals. If it makes your code clear, it's worth considering. If it makes things confusing, it's not a good idea.

For example, you may only have two types of tires, but consider a couple of things:

- How do you know you won't add more later? You don't want to shoot yourself in the foot.
- When writing / reading the code how do you remember that `true` is "summer" and `false` is "winter"? Will you have to maintain that info in your head / always look it up somewhere? Will it be easy to make a mistake? Will it confuse a reader who is unfamiliar with your code?

Think about those kinds of things. In your case, while using a boolean will certainly get the job done, I'd say it's a good use for an `enum`, even if you only have two values right now (or ever). E.g.:

```
enum TireType { WinterTire, SummerTire };
```

Now everything falls into place:

- You can add new types in the future if you'd like, with no major issues.
- A variable `TireType t` documents itself, we know just at a glance that `t` is a tire type.
- There is much less of a chance of mistake when entering values: It'll be very hard to confuse `WinterTire` with `SummerTire`, whereas `true` and `false` discard all semantic meaning.

Comment: Far too late for a jovial "jinx" comment, and you spell "tyre" like an American (ugh!), but have a +1 anyway for a great answer ;) ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was so self-conscious about spelling it that way. I couldn't bring myself to type "tyre", but every time I typed "tire" I could hear the OP groan. By the time I got to the `enum` it was too late to turn back so I just dove right in.

Comment: #firstworldproblems :D

Comment: Is there a reason you chose `enum` over `enum class`? Excellent answer indeed.

Comment: @user2296177 Nope, there is no reason in particular.

Answer (score 7):

A boolean has two options, but those options are "true" or "false" (or, occasionally, "yes" and "no").

We do not generally represent other variables with two options as booleans.

If you have tyre types (of which there currently so happen to be two), I would suggest `enum`s for this.

As always, there are exceptions. If your tyre types are "tyre with oil on it" and "tyre without oil on it", then you could use a boolean called `tyreHasOilOnIt`.

Really, it is up to you.

Answer (score 6):

A boolean type is generally a value with precisely two values, one being truthy and the other falsy. This can to some degree be bent to other meanings. In your case when I saw discussion of tyre type I had no idea what the two values would mean untill reading the comments.

In my opinion when the value isn't self explanatory like this I would not use a boolean.

In your case, if the types of tyre are known at the time you write the program I would use an `enum` of some sort, and if they are not known just a plain string.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oops, I'm going to blame this one on the Android app not telling me someone else had answered while I was typing haha. Have a +1

Comment: Back atcha Mr Vality :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest don't use either enum or bool type for tyre type as a possible variable/attribute may change as you specified yes/no or Winter/Summer . Its better to use it as short int which values you can track or map with respect to yes,no,winter,summer . This will allow you to assign or change as per your need and class will never need a change.

```
Example :

Class car
{

// we will use tyre type to map enum
//type and other type if required
```

int tyreType;

```
};

enum tyre_type_t
{
//default value is considered 100
// since we can use previous     
 //value any other purpose.
WINTER = 100,
SUMMER
}

int main()
{
Car obj;

obj.tyreType = 1; // Yes
obj.tyreType = 0; // No
obj.tyreType = WINTER;
// Now we can assig enum.          
 // values     //too.

return  0;
}
```

Happy Coding

Comment: Well, an enum accomplishes all of the things you outline in your final sentence, with the added benefit of a semantically interesting type name, and compile-time type checking. Is it possible that you misread the question? The OP did not specify "yes" and "no" as valid tire types, only "winter" and "summer".

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer @YogeshBadhe - I don't understand how you intend to use an int here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Example :

Class car
{

// we will use tyre type to map enum
//type and other type if required
```

int tyreType;

```
};

enum tyre_type_t
{
//default value is considered 100
// since we can use previous     
 //value any other purpose.
WINTER = 100,
SUMMER
}

int main()
{
Car obj;

obj.tyreType = 1; // Yes
obj.tyreType = 0; // No
obj.tyreType = WINTER;
// Now we can assig enum.          
 // values     //too.

return  0;
}
```

Happy Coding